# PHP unable to load ZIP module

Tags: php, zip, archlinux

PHP 7.0.14 (Arch Linux) complains with the following error

```
 PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
 '/usr/lib/php/modules/zip.so' - libzip.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

`locate libzip.so.4` finds nothing

Looks like I have a newer version of libzip (libzip.so.5)

```
$ locate zip.so     
/usr/lib/libminizip.so
/usr/lib/libminizip.so.1
/usr/lib/libminizip.so.1.0.0
/usr/lib/libzip.so
/usr/lib/libzip.so.5
/usr/lib/libzip.so.5.0.0
/usr/lib/gnome-vfs-2.0/modules/libgzip.so
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk/jre/lib/amd64/libzip.so
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/jre/lib/amd64/libzip.so
/usr/lib/php/modules/zip.so
```

**How can I rebuild it in Arch Linux for php-7.0.14 with the new zip lib?**

I already have `/var/cache/pacman/pkg/php-7.0.14-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz`

Comment: `sudo pacman -S php` you are running an old version of PHP (latest available on the repo is 7.16-1).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-zip
```

and also install

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-gd
```

Then after restart apache

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Comment: It's Arch Linux as I mentioned :) On Ubuntu/Debian it might work

Comment: I also have the same problem, but both packages were installed on my Ubuntu System.